# Multiple Inheritance/Polymorphism Homework

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I have a homework assignment coming up that I am a bit confused on. The assignment basically states that we are to use Multiple Inheritance/Polymorphism to make 21 classes in a hierarchical manner. I know how the hierarchy is supposed to look on paper but I was wondering exactly what syntax I should be using for this.

First few examples are Organism(head of "tree", Animal(child of organism), Plant(child of organism), Ectotherm(child of Animal), and Endotherm (child of Animal), etc...

If you want to see the actual assignment, here's a link.
[Homework 10](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/spring13/ds/hw/10_organism_inheritance/hw.pdf)

I don't need exact code but help on use of the virtual syntax and such would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: The example given in the assignment handout is a good start. I think you should start by trying to do it on your own and come back here with concrete questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Have you tried [getting help here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/spring13/ds/getting_help.html) first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start off with your base class and derive from it. With the class tree you described, you don't need virtual bases. But you'd probably want to add some functionality to your classes, so I'd give you an example:

```
class Organism                          // abstract class (no instantiation)
{
  public:
    virtual string getName() = 0;       // because this method is pure (no body)
};

class Animal : public Organism {};      // also abstract

class Dog : public Animal               // not abstract
{
  public:
    string getName() { return "dog"; }  // because here's an implementation
};
```

I know this site is not for homework but maybe it helps not only you but also your classmates =D

Comment: Thank you. This is basically the start I was looking for. Also, I found that http://www.learncpp.com/ chapters 11 and 12 provide excellent instruction on this category. Thanks again!